# Creating Urls for file on servers and sending them in mail (Python)

Tags: python, email, automation

I have a script setup to send mails daily to group of people with an attachment in it. I am using python with sendgrid api. I am not able to send email when attachment is more than 25MB. I have all my files saved on server. Is there a way to create a url for these saved files and send this link over email so that users can download the file ? Or is there is any better way to handle large files over email.

Note: I have automated this mailing system. So cannot send it manually each time it fails.

Comment: you might upload it to google drive(or similar alternative) and just send the link. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#python

Comment: I tried uploading to google drive from python. It was successful from local but from server it is not possible. Reason is it opens a link initially in the local browser which is not possible on the server.

Comment: Basically it creates local webserver and auto handles authentication.